# C++ Sorting list containing class

Tags: c++, list, sorting

I have a small problem. I'm currently writing a code for tournament handling and I came out with an idea that the best way to keep teams in order in memory will be a list.
Now, I'm trying to sort list cointaing Team class that is containg points records.
Here's the class declaration:

```
#include "player.h"
#include <string>

class Team {
Player** Gracz;
std::string Name;
int TP, STP;
int Total;

public:
Team();
Team(Player* gracz1, Player* gracz2, Player* gracz3, Player* gracz4, Player*     gracz5, Player* gracz6, std::string name);
~Team();

void SetTeam();
void SetTeam(Player gracz1, Player gracz2, Player gracz3, Player gracz4, Player gracz5, Player gracz6, std::string name);
void SetTP(int tp);
void SetSTP(int stp);

std::string GetTeam();
int GetTotal();
int GetTP();
int GetSTP();

bool operator<(Team& team);
bool operator>(Team& team);

void PrintTeam();
};
```

And here's the program code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "player.h"
#include "team.h"
#include <list>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
Player *p;
Team *t1, *t2, *t3, *t4;
list<Team> x;
list<Team>::iterator it;

p=new Player("a","a","a");

t1=new Team(p,p,p,p,p,p,"A");
t2=new Team(p,p,p,p,p,p,"B");
t3=new Team(p,p,p,p,p,p,"C");
t4=new Team(p,p,p,p,p,p,"D");

x.push_back(*t1);
x.push_back(*t2);
x.push_back(*t3);
x.push_back(*t4);

cout<<"Turniej: "<<endl;
for(it=x.begin();it!=x.end();++it)
    cout<<" "<<(*it).GetTeam();
cout<<endl;

t1->SetTP(15);
t2->SetTP(4);
t3->SetTP(8);
t4->SetTP(8);
t3->SetSTP(15);
t4->SetSTP(65);

x.sort(); 

cout<<"Turniej: "<<endl;
for(it=x.begin();it!=x.end();++it)
    cout<<" "<<(*it).GetTeam();
cout<<endl;

return 0;
}
```

So I'd like to sort list by firstly TPs and then by STPs and it's included in declaration of overloaded operator <. When I'm printing list, I get A,B,C,D before the sorting and the same after the sorting, instead of A,D,C,B after. Where's my mistake?

Thanks for help.

Comment: What does your `operator<` function look like?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here the object is copied, and its copy is pushed into a container:

```
x.push_back(*t1);
/* the same for others */
```

Here you modify the original object, but the copy in the container is unchanged:

```
t1->SetTP(15);
```

Comment: Thank you! How I could be so blind?